# How do I disable the use of sudo -s command ssh?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

In Google Compute Engine to register a private key on the console, how do I disable the use of sudo -s command ssh?

Comment: Can you elaborate further on your goal? As it is, this question is barely answerable.

Comment: The OP means that, by default, if you add a new user's SSH key through the web interface, that user will have full unrestricted passwordless sudo access on the VM after logging in via SSH. The OP is asking how to disable sudo for that newly added user.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you're trying to lock sudoers out from full access of the root account. Even if you prevent sudoers from gaining root's powers in the fashion you describe, there are other ways they can get there. examples:

- sudo bash
- sudo vi (and then run shell commands from within vi)
- sudo less (and then run shell commands from within less)
- sudo vi /etc/rc.sysinit (it's a free-for-all upon next reboot...)